# Bootstrap's javascript requires jquery error in our client side login

Tags: javascript, jquery

So we are currently building a client side CEF login for a game server. It works but we still keep getting this annoying error on launch client side:

> "Bootstrap's javascript requires jquery. jquery must be included
>   before bootstrap's javascript"

I have checked everywhere and everything seems to be in the correct order though I'm likely very wrong! Here is the order we have it in the head tag:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title</title>


<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: could you maybe check this with the cdn link to jquery? It may be that the file you have is faulty

Comment: most likely this `<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` points to the wrong path or file

Comment: see if console is throwing 404 for the `jquery` file

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far. I have tried using "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" seems to not make a difference and no errors seem to be created. It's really strange.

Comment: did you check if in console and in network section there is a 404 for the jquery library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the google or microsoft CDN? I would check

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't hurt to try and see if that works!